# JSON JsonConvert.DeserializeObject error

Tags: .net, vb.net, json.net

I'm having a problem that I don't know how to solve.

I'm trying to resolve the error:

> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'name.jsonPrjData' because the type requires
>   a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly

I have found similar pages on stack-overflow and tried what was proposed in the answers but I'm not able to figure out what is the problem.

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

    Public Class jsonPrjData
        Public Property sapcode() As String
        Public Property prjCode() As String
        Public Property prjDescript() As String
    End Class

    Public Class Form1

        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        End Sub

        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
            Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://localhost/json/")
            Dim obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of jsonPrjData)(result)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

And the JSON looks like this:

> [{"sapcode":"xxxx","prjCode":"xxxx","prjDescript":"xxxx"},{"sapcode":"xxxx","prjCode":"xxxx","prjDescript":"xxxx"}]

Comment: I think its because you are trying to deserialize an array of json objects into a single  jsonPrjData .NET object. You need to desirialize into a set or list.

Comment: how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key part of the error message is: `Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])`.  The message scrolls giving a clearer idea what to do:

> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or **change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array**. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

The square brackets indicate the data is an array (e.g. [1, 2, 3]) and also the fact that there is obviously 2 repeating sets of data of identical structure there.  So:

```
' Note the added ()
Dim prjData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of jsonPrjData())(result)
```

As the latter part of the error message indicates, you can also deserialize to a `List(of T)`:

```
Dim prjList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of jsonPrjData))(result)
```

Of course since the target object is declared locally, they will only exist in that click event.